# CollapsingToolbarLayout enterAlwaysCollapsed don't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Setting enterAlwaysCollapsed to the CollapsingToolbarLayout does not work as expected. The toolbar still gets completely expanded right away even if the RecyclerView has not finished scrolling. I want it to expand only upto a min height when scroll up in the the middle of RecyclerView list and when scroll reaches the top of the RecyclerView it should expand to its complete height.
Android doc says, Assuming enterAlways is declared and you have specified a minHeight, you can also specify enterAlwaysCollapsed. When this setting is used, your view will only appear at this minimum height. Only when scrolling reaches to the top will the view expand to its full height.
i have set minHeight but still its not wokring.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/bg"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/bg"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/action_bar_wall" />

                <rana.jatin.tbd.customViews.MyTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_group_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="@string/my_groups"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/seventeen_sp" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_home_posts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rv_wall"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the Toolbar's height to `?attr/actionBarSize`?